# Objective C: Making Object in .h Files

Tags: objective-c, class, object, xcode5

I am using Xcode 5.x and I want to make an object of another class in my second class's .h file. So a myclass1 object in myclass2.h. Here is a replica of my MyClass2.h (The name is different and the bulk code is gone):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyClass1.h"
@class MyClass1 ;

MyClass1 * object1 ;

@interface MyClass2 : NSObject{

}
@end
```

However, I cannot type: MyClass1 *object = [MyClass1 new] ; because it is not a compile time constant. I understand the error, but where do I put the [MyClass1 new]? Without it, the object is created, but when I use it in MyClass2.m, I cannot access the methods of MyClass1. Will I have to make the object in main.m? I am making an iOS app (if that helps).

Comment: That's what the init method is for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The header file (.h) is really primarily used to declare instance variables, properties, and expose functions, you don't want to be running any code there.

Your header should look something like:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MyClass1.h"

@interface MyClass2 : NSObject {
    MyClass1 *instanceOfMyClass1;
}

@end
```

And in your implementation file (.m) you can then do this in whatever function (init/viewDidLoad/whatever) you'd like:

```
instanceOfMyClass1 = [MyClass1 new];
```

Comment: OK thanks! I was hoping the initialization could be done in the header but whatever. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, marking this as the solution would be appreciated. Thanks!